# Restoring a bare-metal backup fails (0x80070057 error) on Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, backup-restoration

I'm trying to create a backup of our one of our domain controllers in case of a catastrophic failure, and I'm looking into ways to make one effectively.

So far, I'm been very unsuccessful in getting any of the recovery methods to actually WORK, which is VERY worrying.

Also, this IS connected with [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/949678/backing-up-dc-for-a-catastrophic-case), albeit I'd like to focus on something else here.

The smallest DC we have is one running on a VM in Hyper-V and it's a perfect "testing" environment. The Hyper-V host is a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine while the DC itself is a Windows Server 2016. I used Windows Server Backup on the DC to create a bare-metal image, and copied it to a network drive.

Now, I want to test the recovery process, so on my own machine (a Windows 10 running Hyper-V) I've created a VM with a C drive, a DVD with the Windows Server 2016 image and another drive to which I copied the backup folder created by Windows Server Backup.

The restore operation recognized the backup image, but failed to recover with the 0x80070057 error. Googling this suggests this is due to BIOS / UEFI differences, but the original DC is running on a Generation 2 VM, as was my VM for testing, so clearly this isn't it. The only other thing I can think of is that the source VM has a version 5 configuration, while Windows 10 creates VMs with configuration versions 8.3. The only change in "hardware" is that the VM I'm trying to recover to has an additional drive where the backup is stored.

So, does this mean such a recovery is impossible (as lowering the configuration version in Hyper-V isn't supported as far as I know)? I'm really scratching my head here; I'd imagine that's the whole point of a bare-metal recovery, especially when dealing with Windows Serve (i.e. something you WANT to be able to recover, which might be quite critical).

How SHOULD I create a backup of the source VM then if I want to be able to restore it later to, potentially, unknown hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the issue. Apparently when the various version of Hyper-V across Windows Server versions are using different code for the network adapters. I was able to restore the machine after removing the network adapter from it. Of course I can re-add it later, after the restore is complete.

EDIT: It's also possible to create a VM using PowerShell `New-VM` with the additional parameter `-version 5.0`, which creates a VM compatible with one from a Windows Server 2012 R2 (network card included).